# rails select_tag display different option values than select value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I have a select_tag that displays quantity and price together:

```
<% quant_price(quantity) = logic for quantity price breaks %>
<% @quantities = Array.new(1000) {|i| ((i + 1) * 10) } %>
<%= select_tag(:quantity, options_for_select(@quantities.map {|q| ["#{q} ($#{quant_price(q)}/ea)", q] }, @line_item.present? ? @line_item.quantity : 10), :class => "quantity-picker", :style => "float: right; width: 90px;") %>
```

This makes the select options that appear when the user clicks on the quantity picker look like:

```
10 ($5.00/ea)
20 ($4.80/ea)
30 ($4.60/ea)
etc...
```

But when they select an option, the select box reads "10 ($5.00/ea)".  I want it to just read the `q` value in the select view, not the extra stuff.

How can I have it so that the select box/quantity picker just reads "10"?

Comment: What is it that you actual goal is here? When you pass pairs to `options_for_select` the first is used as the text and the second is used as the value. Options in the browser don't automatically change their text to their value when you select them. If you want that behavior you need to use javascript.

Comment: The goal is to have only the value of the option show in the 'select' view after the user chooses; not the first text string.  I tried to use JS to alter the innerHTML, but that wasn't working.

Comment: @Alex Are you expecting to show selected value instead of showing always first option as selected?

Comment: @SampatBadhe Yes...I want to show the value selected in the select view after the user clicks the option

Comment: @Alex how about showing `quant_price` as `title(tooltip on hover)` for select item?

`<%= select_tag(:quantity, options_for_select(@quantities.map {|q| [q, q, {:title => "#{q} ($#{quant_price(q)}/ea)" }] }, @line_item.present? ? @line_item.quantity : 10), :class => "quantity-picker", :style => "float: right; width: 90px;") %>`